# How to execute script on my Ubuntu via PHP from site

Tags: bash, scripts, apache2, php

How can I use PHP to execute a script on my Ubuntu server? The site is hosted on the same machine obviously.

I read about `exec_shell()` and tried this

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("ls /var/www");
    echo "<h1>Output: " . $output . "</h1>";
?>
```

But it didn't echo anything on the site, have I misunderstood the function?

Plan is to make a script run on my Ubuntu PC, restarting a few game servers once I click a button on the website.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php): "The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output." Potentially an error have occurred, likely because the process runs with username that does not have access to `/var/www`. Check the permissions returned with `ls -ld /var/www` in shell,  perhaps also try different command in `shell_exec()`.

Comment: Try `$output = shell_exec('ls /var/www');` and `echo "<h1>Output: $output</h1>";`, that’s how [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) does it.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy What user is used for the `shell_exec()` commands?

Comment: @dessert Didn't work either, sadly

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström You could find it via `echo $USER > /tmp/test.txt` I don't have PHP installed to tell

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy It won't create the file even

Comment: The example from the question works as it is expected for me. `echo $USER` will fail within php, becauese `$USER` looks like unset php variable ... use  `<?php echo "<h1>Output: " . shell_exec("whoami") . "</h1>"; ?>` instead to find that, the run user is `www-data` :)

Comment: @pa4080 So `shell_exec()` doesn't actually spawn a shell (in which case it's a false advertisement then :) ) ? or is it a case of quoting issues ?

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström, you said *"But it didn"t echo anything on the site"*, but if the discussed function fail you must see, at least, `<h1>Output:</h1>` in the browser - doesn't it?

Comment: did you look the generated page source, it may contain something and help to forward

Comment: @pa4080 Well yeah, but I meant the actual shell_exec didn't echo any response

Comment: I remember I faced this about 3 years ago, and this is how I solved it: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45650439/8128190)

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code and in my server it works correctly. It gives the following output:

```
Output: apps awstats cgi-bin clients conf error html icons ispconfig manual mauco.org med-01.uc.cl php-fcgi-scripts usage
```

That are the folders in /var/www

I think you may have a privileges issue. What happens if you try with this command:

```
  $output = shell_exec("ls /tmp");
```

You can also check if what user is being used by apache/nginx

```
 $output = shell_exec("whoami");
```

Please include screenshots of your results.

Comment: `passthru();` seems to work fine, but still shell_exec doesn't. Using passhthru I found out that apache is using www-data as its user

Comment: This   $output = shell_exec("ls /tmp"); gives you no output?

Comment: Correct. Doesn't work at all